# Rsync hangs / freezes when trying to sync a Symfony project via Windows XP

Tags: php, windows, symfony1, rsync

My Symfony 1.3 project does not sync correctly with my SSH server.

I have cygWin and cwRsync installed and my local version of PHP is 5.2.11

I did not have any issues on any early versions of Symfony 1.0 but now my command line tools either hang with no response, or they close without letting me review the output of the script.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify what is the relationship between rsync and php?

Comment: @ajreal Symfony uses PHP to call rsync commands via the command line.

Comment: u can directly use rsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the sfProjectDeployTask.class.php file in your PEAR folder

For me it was here:

```
\php5.2.11\PEAR\symfony13\task\project
```

On line 162 find the code like this:

```
$command = "rsync $dryRun $parameters -e $ssh ./ $user$host:$dir";
```

and change it to read:

```
$command = "start cmd /k rsync $dryRun $parameters -e $ssh ./ $user$host:$dir";
```